# Trying to understand creating a MIPS pipeline diagram

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, mips32

I have to create a pipeline diagram executing the following MIPS code.  It's a 5-stage pipeline.  Both the `mul` and `div` instructions use 4 execute instructions.  To quote the assignment for the mul instruction

> This means that a multiply instruction runs through the pipeline as follows:  `F-D-X0-X1-X2-X3-M-W`  and  up  to  four  multiply  instructions  maybe  in-flight  at  a  time.   All other instruction types are blocked from the execute stage while any of the multiply stages are being used.

and for div

> This means that a divide instruction runs through the pipeline as follows:  `F-D-X0-X0-X0-X0-M-W`. All other instructions are blocked from the execute stage while a division is being done.

Here is the MIPS code.

```
xor   $r0, $r0, $r0
addiu $r1, $r0, 10
j L1
loop: 
    lw    $r3, 0($r2)
    mul   $r4, $r3, $r3
    mul   $r3, $r3, $r1
    addiu $r0, $r0, 1
    div   $r3, $r4, $r3
    sw    $r3, 0($r2)
    addiu $r2, $r2, 4
L1: 
bne $r0, $r1, -8
```

The full question I have to answer for this is:

> **Q:** Draw a pipeline diagram (table) showing the execution of the MIPS code through the first iteration of the loop, without bypassing.
>   Assume data hazards and structural hazards
>   are resolved using only stalling.  Assume the processor assumes branches are not taken, until they are resolved.
>   What is the CPI of the entire program?

Here is what I got:

[image: MIPS Pipeline Diagram]

My biggest snag came from trying to understand what to do when it came to the jump instruction.  As you can see I just kind of went about business as usual but I know that is most likely completely wrong.  I'm fairly confident I handled the instructions after `mul` and `div` properly, it's just the `j L1` instruction I'm not confident with regards since I have no examples to refer to.  CPI as an after thought though I'm assuming I just take the total cycles and divide it by the number of instructions?  So in this case it would be `(32 cycles)/(11 instructions)` so `CPI = 2.91`?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would answer the question, because I think it's well asked. But I think your MIPS code is wrong. It jumps to `L1` and then loops infinitely at the `bne` line which steps back `-8`.

Comment: @Konrad It's just the example given, the code is copied straight from the assignment.  Understanding it's first iteration is good enough.  All of our assignments has always been typically based on first iteration if there are any loops unless otherwise stated.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Right. But the first iteration clearly doesn't do what you think. The `mul` instructions are never run.

Comment: @konrad  Here is the complete assignment.  Am I totally misunderstanding my own assignment?  https://www.dropbox.com/s/e72zqjtw67amiv9/cmpe110-hw22.pdf?dl=0

Comment: So, I guess I misunderstood. The `bne` jumps back `8` instructions, when I thought it was `2`. So I will withdraw the suggestion that the code is wrong, but you still are misunderstanding it. The `j` instruction is executed, then the `lw` instruction (delay slot), then the `bne`. You seem to be assuming that the instructions are executed in the order given, but there are branches and jumps so that's clearly not the case.

Comment: Ok so right after the jump when I hit the lw instruction in the loop does it get fetched and then stalled as I process the bne instruction?  and then once the bne instruction is in the pipeline would i start up the lw instruction again at execution of bne or at w and then finish the loop?  Sorry for the trouble, just having a hard time grasping this aspect of it.  Thank you again for all the help

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question, you should first know about branch prediction. Branches can cause you to either fetch from a new location or continue fetching sequentially as normal. Waiting for the branch condition to resolve which address you should fetch from often causes stalling and wastes some cycles. To overcome that processors use branch prediction or speculation, they assume a branch is taken or non-taken and continue fetching and execution based on this assumption. Once the branch condition is resolved, the processor knows whether its assumption was right or wrong, if it is right you continue execution as normal and you have saved a couple of precious cycles instead of stalling. if the assumption turns out to be wrong you flush the wrongly executed instructions out of your pipeline and the penalty is usually the same as if you stalled waiting for the branch to resolve. Better branch prediction algorithms have a higher probability of correctly guessing whether to branch or not.

As you stated in your question

> Assume the processor assumes branches are not taken, until they are resolved.

Your processor uses a static branch prediction. It always assumes the branch is not taken. if the assumption is found to be wrong the instructions are flushed from the pipeline.

This applies to branches but not jumps because only branches are dependent on a condition. jumps execute unconditionally and do not prediction. so after executing that jump instruction you should have continued directly from L1.